# Why is the $n$-sphere a Smooth Manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I want to know how the $n$-sphere is a smooth manifold?

I'm unable to understand the theory of differentiable structure on the $n$-sphere.

Please tell me any suggested reading for a good start on differentiable manifolds.

Presently I am following John M. Lee's book which is quite difficult for me to understand.

Comment: Lee`s book is in fact a good introduction. Maybe having a look at Wikipedia first is helpfull; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold

Answer (score 7):

Write $f(x)=\|x\|^2$. This is a smooth map $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. The $n$-sphere is given as

$$S^n = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\,:\,\|x\|^2=1\} = f^{-1}(1)$$

Since $1$ is a regular value of $f$ (check it!), $S^n$ is a smooth $n$ dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by the [submanifold theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem).

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for a more explicit description of an atlas (rather than a more implicit proof that it is a smooth manifold, like using the submanifold theorem in TooOldforMath's answer, although that is certainly the easier way of proving it), the standard way is to choose the following cover:

$$ U_1=S^n\setminus \{(0,0,\cdots,0,1\} \text{ and } U_2=S^n\setminus \{(0,0,\cdots,0,-1\}, $$

and use [stereographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) as the homeomorphisms from $U_1$ and $U_2$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.  This explicitly defines an atlas.